Hessian for log likelihood of regression with respect to covariance matrix
I am interested in the residual covariance of a multivariate regression model. The regression is
$$
Y_t = X_t \beta + \varepsilon_t
$$
and I have a log likelihood as follows
$$
\mathcal{L}(\Sigma) = \frac{T}{2} \log | \Sigma^{-1} | - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{t=1}^T \varepsilon_t^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} \varepsilon_t
$$
omitting constants and assuming $\Sigma$ is the residual covariance matrix. Additionally, $Y_t \in \mathbb{R}^{N}, X_t \in \mathbb{R}^{N}, \varepsilon_t \in \mathbb{R}^{N}, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ are the dimensions of the variables.
I can obtain the gradient with respect to $\Sigma$ as follows
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma} \mathcal{L}(\Sigma) = -\frac{T}{2} \Sigma^{-1} + \frac{1}{2} \Sigma^{-1} \varepsilon_t^\top \varepsilon_t \Sigma^{-1}
$$
My question is, is there a closed form for the hessian of the log likelihood? More specifically, I want to obtain the maximum eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of the hessian to obtain the Lipschitz constant for a gradient descent algorithm. This is now more difficult because we have to take derivatives with respect to inverses of matrices instead of scalar.
I believe the result is a four dimensional tensor, but this can be flatted to obtain a Kronecker product of dimension $N^2 \times N^2$. Then I want to obtain the maximum eigenvalue of this form.

Welcome to the site, Ivan! If this is a learning exercise, I think that's great, and a few hours with the matrix cookbook's first chapter(https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) should do it. But if you are doing this for a practical purpose, why not just use a line search method to determine the step size? This will be much cheaper than trying to find the largest eigenvalue of a matrix quadratic in size of the data, and will probably actually give you better steps too.

Thank you for the resource! Indeed I can use the chapter on matrix derivatives to guide my work. In terms of the line search, I did not think of that, and will also look into that direction!

The best place to start in my view would be a "backtracking line search"; super easy to implement and quite effective!
